# How to set only border bottom color in css of a division

Tags: css

How can i do so.
I want to change the color of div's only bottom side.

```
I tried border: 1px solid green
```

Comment: Use `border-bottom-color: green` for change the border bottom color only

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
div{
   border-bottom: 1px solid green;
  }
```